# Como resolver problemas no display flex do firefox

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Criei este portfólio ele funciona perfeitamente no chrome, porém no firefox a tag button que fica sobreposta na tag img (para fazer o efeito de sombra e abrir um modal) aparece como um quinto item, gerando scroll horizontal e não fazendo o efeito de sombreamento quando o mouse passa em cima, gostaria de saber como deixar sobreposto no firefox!

Como fica no chrome:(como deveria ficar)
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Como fica no firefox:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<style type="text/css">

    .portfolio{margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 86px;display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}

    .projetos{width: 25%;}

    .projetos-content{position: relative;}

    .projetos-img{width: 100%;}

    .sombra{background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0); width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; transition: 0.5s; border: none;}

    .sombra:hover{background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); cursor: pointer;}

</style>
```

```
<div class="portfolio">

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

      <img src="1.jpg" class="projetos-img">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

      <img src="2.jpg" class="projetos-img">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

      <img src="3.jpg" class="projetos-img">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

      <img src="1.jpg" class="projetos-img">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Alguns elementos CSS necessitam de prefixos para funcionar em diferentes navegadores, não tenho certeza se é a solução mas vale a pena dar uma olhada nesse link da Tableless que fala sobre Prefixos (https://tableless.com.br/prefixos-dos-browsers-a-web-precisa-de-voce/) e nesse Link da Mozilla que fala sobre Flexbox (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/CSS/Usando_caixas_flexiveis_css). Além disso, esse site aplica automaticamente alguns prefixos para o código que você inserir (https://autoprefixer.github.io/)

Comment: muito obrigado vou ler e tentar aplicar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo basicamente o que faltou no seu código foi definir uma referencia no eixo `X`, repare que vc declarou um `top` como `0`, que seria o seixo Y, porém não declarou nada pro eixo `X`, vc pode usar ou um `left: 0;` como eu usei ou `right: 0;` que tb da certo. Então na classe `.sombra` eu adicionei tb um `left: 0;`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja como fica. Pode testar no Fire Fox que vai dar certo. Essa particularidade vai de browser para browser, não tem muito o que explicar nesse "erro", isso tem mais a ver com o motor de renderização do browser, que no FireFox é diferente do Chrome....

```css
.portfolio{margin-bottom: 100px; margin-top: 86px;display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;}

.projetos{width: 25%;}

.projetos-content{position: relative;}

.projetos-img{width: 100%;}

.sombra{background: rgba(255,255,255,0.0); width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; transition: 0.5s; border: none;}

.sombra:hover{background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); cursor: pointer;}
```

```html
<div class="portfolio">

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

      <img  class="projetos-img" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

        <img  class="projetos-img" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

        <img  class="projetos-img" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="projetos">

    <div class="projetos-content">

      <img  class="projetos-img" src="https://placecage.com/100/100">

      <button type="button" class="sombra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"></button>

    </div>

  </div> 

</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o problema!

Comment: @DeMarchi se vc não definir de onde o elemento deve começar em um dos eixos, o browser não entende de onde o elemento começa e onde termina. Mas legal que resolveu! Considere marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone  `✔` abaixo das setinhas da minha resposta. Assim o site não fica com a pergunta sem resposta aceita, mesmo já tendo sido resolvido. Depois se aparecer outra resposta que te atenda melhor vc pode mudar o aceite para ela.